# dataweave 2.0 transformation

Tags: transformation, dataweave

I have a XML file which has nested elements and few elements has attributes to that. I want to convert this XML to json using dataweave 2.0 and the json has to contain the attributes.

```
Using the json generated from previous step, I want to recreate the original XML

Ex: <elem1>
<elem2 attr=Val>
<elem3 attr=Val>
</elem3>
</elem2>
</elem1>

Thanks in advance
```

Comment: JSON doesn't support attributes. How do you need to map them to JSON? Please add a n example JSON output.

Answer (score 2):

**JSON with Attributes to XML with Attributes:**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml

fun collectAttributes(elem:Object) = 
    elem filterObject ((value, key, index) -> key contains  "@" )

fun putAttributes(elem: Object) =
    elem mapObject ((value, key, index) -> value match {
        case is Object -> do {
            var attr = collectAttributes(value)
            var withoutAttr = value -- attr
            ---
            (key) @((attr)): 
                if (keysOf(withoutAttr) contains "__text" as Key)
                    withoutAttr."__text" 
                else 
                    putAttributes(withoutAttr)
        }
        else -> (key): value
    })
        
---
putAttributes(payload)
```

I'm not sure if it is fully generalized to take every JSON with Attributes, but works in your case.

**XML to JSON with Attributes:**
You could try the writer property `writeAttributes`.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json writeAttributes=true
---
payload
```

https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-json#properties

Comment: Thanks Christian for this. I got the first part of this. Now using the JSON which gets created with this transformation, i need to recreate the original xml. Any inputs on that?

Comment: Please add that to the question or create a new one.

Comment: Thanks Christian for the function. It works but only 1 minor concern is that the attribute starts with @ within XML element. Anyway to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using this script for converting back to xml

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml writeDeclaration=false
fun json2xml(data) = data mapObject (v, k, i) -> {
    ((k) @(
        (
            if(v is Object and !isEmpty(searchForAttr(v))) searchForAttr(v)
            else null
        )
    ): v match {
        case is Object -> if(namesOf(v) contains("__text")) searchForText(v) else json2xml(v)
        else -> v
    }) if (!(k contains "@") and !(k contains "__text"))
}
fun searchForAttr(v) = v mapObject {
    (($$[1 to -1]): $) if(($$ as String) startsWith("@")) 
}
fun searchForText(v) = v mapObject {
    (($$):$) if(($$ as String) == "__text")
} pluck $
---
json2xml(payload)
```

I tried it with a much more complex xml structure and it did convert back to the original xml, however the initial conversion to JSON (using the `writeAttributes` option) leaves out xml namespaces so if your original input has namespaces may need to go another route with the JSON conversion.

Comment: application/dw is meant only for debugging and using it in production applications can cause performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

Using Christian's approach , you could update the script to remove "@" from the attribute keys:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml

fun collectAttributes(elem:Object) = 
    elem filterObject ((value, key, index) -> key contains  "@" )

fun putAttributes(elem: Object) =
    elem mapObject ((value, key, index) -> value match {
        case is Object -> do {
            var attr = (collectAttributes(value))
            var attrfinal = attr mapObject {
                ($$ replace "@" with ""):(($))
            }
            var withoutAttr = value -- attr
            ---
            (key) @((attrfinal)): 
                if (keysOf(withoutAttr) contains "__text" as Key)
                    withoutAttr."__text" 
                else 
                    putAttributes(withoutAttr)
        }
        else -> (key): value
      })
        
---
putAttributes(payload)
```